# Running MS SQL server in docker refuses connection

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have issues connecting with MSSQL Server Management Studio to my running docker container.

A beginner in docker.

I have created a following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqlserver:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/sql_volume/_data
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "pa55w0rd!"
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
    ports:
      - "1533:1534"
  adventureworks_service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}adventureworksservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AdventureWorks_Service/Dockerfile
```

this docker file should start a MSSQL Database and the adventureworks_service project located in my solution.

this docker-compose is located in it's own Docker project, in the solution. created with the "add docker support" for my Web API project

assuming everything is correctly setup, I should be able to connect to the sql server on `localhost:1533`, using SQL server authentication with login `Express` and password `pa55w0rd!`.

I get following error right after attempting to connect (no timeouts, etc.)

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider : TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
```

Does anyone know how I can access this server / container?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _using SQL server authentication with login Express and password pa55w0rd!._ Its login **SA** and NOT _Express_.

Comment: I'm having same issues with login as SA, as well. I'm able to connect to the server using `docker exec -it <container_id|container_name> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password>` in Powershell. This issue only persists when connecting to container spun using `docker-compose.yaml`. When run using `docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`, I'm able to connect from SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

The port in mssql should be `1433` rather than `1534`, try this

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqlserver:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/sql_volume/_data
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "pa55w0rd!"
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"   # the port behind should always be 1433

  adventureworks_service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}adventureworksservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AdventureWorks_Service/Dockerfile
```

then your connection string should be like this

```
Data Source=sqlserver,1433;User Id=SA;Password=pa55w0rd!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `network_mode: "host"` to your compose file.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sqlserver:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/sql_volume/_data
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "pa55w0rd!"
      MSSQL_PID: "Express"
    ports:
      - "1533:1534"
    network_mode: "host"

  adventureworks_service:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}adventureworksservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AdventureWorks_Service/Dockerfile
```

Comment: I'm having same issues. Tried this, but not working.